# How to create a Default Agent Pool in TFS 2015?

Tags: build, release, tfs-2015

This seems to be simple, but what I'm testing here is to delete the Default Agent Pool, and adding it back with the same permissions. For some reason, the newly created pool is not accessible for any user, unless I add it directly to the Agent Queue Users.

When you create a new server, the Default pool available is accessible by all users and any explicit permissions must be set.

- Is there a way to make any other pool behave as the Default Agent Pool and be available for all users when they are creating a new build/deploy?
- Is there a way to give access to a whole project, instead of doing that adding user by user?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal phenomenon. Since this a new agent pool are created by your account.

> Note: By default in an on-premises server, the only member of the
>   account-level Agent Pool Administrators group is the Team Foundation
>   Administrators group.

You need to make sure you had register the agent in the right way. And make sure there had been Network Service Work Account under Agent pool service accounts.

> Users in the Agent Pool Service Accounts group **have permission to
>   listen to the message queue** for the specific pool to receive work.
>   In most cases you should not have to manage members of this group, the
>   agent registration process will take care of it for you. For Team
>   Foundation Server the service account you specify for the agent
>   (commonly Network Service) is automatically added when you register
>   the agent.

More info about the agent pool, please refer the link from MSDN: [Scale out and administer your build and deployment system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/agents/admin#agent-pools)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't recreate it yet. 
1 - I added a new pool, and added in Agent Pool Service Accounts, Network Service
2 - Added a new Agent in that pool using Network Service Account
3 - Created a new build, and still I can't see the agent queue available

I don't see why it is not working yet...

Comment: Did you leave `Auto-Provision Queue in Project Collections` selected? This setting ensures all collections have a queue to access the pool. The system creates a queue for existing collections and whenver a collection is created. You can double check this setting (right-click the pool). And also follow the steps in this link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows  to deploy the agent on your build server and try again.